# Strange behavior when combining TopAppBar + Swiper + SmartTiles in Kivymd

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Kivy : 2.2.1
Kivymd : 1.2.0.dev

Hi. I get a strange behavior when I combine swiper + TopAppBar + SmartTile: below is the script to the potential bug.

**How to get to the bug**:

1. swipe or click in the three dots button (both gets to the bug) and go to the page 2.
2. Click on one of the SmartTile and close it.
3. Click the 3 dots  -----> here is the wrong behavior it goes to the page 1 while I didn't choose page one in the menu.

Here is the minimal code :

```
#kivy 2.2.0
#kivymd 1.2.0dev

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty,ObjectProperty,NumericProperty
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import MDScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.swiper import MDSwiper
from kivymd.uix.button import MDIconButton
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivymd.uix.toolbar import MDTopAppBar
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.imagelist import MDSmartTile

recipes = [[{"title": "recipe" + str(i)}] for i in range(266)]
titles1 = [recipes[i][0]['title'] for i in range(10)]

KV = '''

<MyMDSmartTile>:
  size_hint: 1, None
  
  MDLabel:
    text: root.text

<ItemMenu>:
  appbar: app.root.ids._appbar
  markup: True
  text: "[ref]self.text[/ref]"
  on_touch_down: self.label_click(*args)      

MyMDScreenManager:
  MDScreen:
    name: "screen A"

    MDBoxLayout:
      orientation: "vertical"

      MyMDTopAppBar:
        id: _appbar
        swiper: _swiper
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        right_action_items:
          [
          ["dots-vertical", lambda x: self.menu_appbar(x), "Menu"] # "menu" icon is cool too
          ]

      MyMDSwiper:
        id: _swiper
        appbar: _appbar
        items_spacing: 0

        MDSwiperItem:
          id: _sw1
          index: 1
          
          MDGridLayout:
            id: _grid1
            cols: 2

        MDSwiperItem:
          id: _sw2
          index: 2

          MDGridLayout:
            id: _grid2
            cols: 2

  MDScreen:
    id: _screenB
    name: "screen B"

    MyMDIconButton:
      manager: root
      icon: "close"
      md_bg_color: 1, 1, 1, .6
      x: 12
      pos_hint: {"top": .99}
'''


class MyMDSmartTile(MDSmartTile):
  text = StringProperty()
  manager = ObjectProperty()

  def on_release(self):
    self.manager.current = "screen B"

class MyMDTopAppBar(MDTopAppBar): # see if kv post can be factorized
  swiper = ObjectProperty()
  titles = ["Page 1", "Page 2"]

  def __init__(self,**kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs) 
    self.elevation = 0 # less shadow default 4
    self.title = self.titles[0]
    self.anchor_title= "left"
    self.menu_items = [
        {   
            "viewclass": "ItemMenu", #can be Item
            "height": dp(36), #dp(54)
            "on_release": lambda x=i: self.item_menu(x),
            "index": i,
        } for i in range(2)
        ]

    self.menu_items[0]["text"] = "[b]Page 1[/b]" # can also change [size=16]
    self.menu_items[1]["text"] = "[b]Page 2[/b]"

    self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
        items= self.menu_items,
        width= dp(150), # width_mult=0, #deprecated use width instead
        background_color=self.theme_cls.primary_light,
        )

  def item_menu(self, index):
    self.swiper.set_current(index) # change the menu page
    self.menu.dismiss()

  def menu_appbar(self, button):
    self.menu.caller = button
    self.menu.open()

class ItemMenu(MDLabel): 
    appbar = ObjectProperty()

    def label_click(self, w,touch):
      if w.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        self.appbar.menu.items[self.index]["on_release"]()
        print("end")
        return True   
      return super(ItemMenu, self).on_touch_down(touch)   

class MyMDIconButton(MDIconButton):
  manager = ObjectProperty()
  def on_release(self):
    self.manager.current = "screen A"

class MyMDSwiper(MDSwiper):
  titles = ["Page 1", "Page 2"]
  index = NumericProperty(1)
  appbar = ObjectProperty()

  def on_swipe(self):
    self.index = self.get_current_index()+1
    self.appbar.title = self.titles[self.index-1]

class MyMDScreenManager(MDScreenManager):
  def on_kv_post(self, base_widget):

    for i in range(len(titles1)):
      tile1=MyMDSmartTile(text= titles1[i], manager = self)
      tile2=MyMDSmartTile(text= titles1[i], manager = self)
      self.ids._grid1.add_widget(tile1)
      self.ids._grid2.add_widget(tile2)

class CuistoDingoApp(MDApp):
  def build(self):
    return Builder.load_string(KV)
  

CuistoDingoApp().run()
```